# Most efficient way to access SQL database from shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, shinydashboard, rsqlite

I am currently working on a personal project to make a shiny dashboard that tracks monthly finances (income, expenses, savings, etc) and visualises them. This project is also a tool for me to learn how to apply SQL, so I'm using RSQLite to manage the database.

Currently, I am considering how the shiny app will interface with the SQL database. I've thought of a couple solutions:

1) On session start, the app copies the database whole into a reactive variable, which it works on to do its calculations and generate plots. This could be memory intensive if the database gets very large.
Here is a minimal working example

```
## creating example database
require("RSQLite")
require("shiny")
require("ggplot2")
require("reshape2")

db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "CREATE TABLE db 
            (month TEXT,
             income REAL,
             expense REAL,
             savings REAL)")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "INSERT INTO db VALUES
            ('September',
            4000,
            2800,
            1200)")
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
            "INSERT INTO db VALUES
            ('October',
            4000,
            3000,
            1000)")

## copy db into reactive
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)


  app <- shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      textOutput("avg.spend"),
      textOutput("avg.save"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      df <- reactiveValues(x = dbGetQuery(conn = db, 'SELECT * FROM db'))
      output$avg.spend <- renderText({
        expense <- paste0("Average expenses: $", mean(df$x$expense))
        print(expense)
      })
      output$avg.save <- renderText({
        savings <- paste0("Average savings: $", mean(df$x$savings))
        print(savings)
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        df.melt <- melt(df$x, id = "month")
        p <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(month)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = value, fill = variable), position = "identity")
        plot(p)
      })
    }
  )

  runApp(app)
}
```

2) Whenever calculations need to be done or plots need to be generated, the app queries the SQL database to get just the entries it needs. However, this may mean multiple repetitive queries.
Example here (showing only the shiny app portion to avoid repetition):

```
app <- shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      textOutput("avg.spend"),
      textOutput("avg.save"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$avg.spend <- renderText({
        qe <- dbGetQuery(conn = db, 'SELECT expense FROM db')
        expense <- paste0("Average expenses: $", mean(qe$expense))
        print(expense)
      })
      output$avg.save <- renderText({
        qs <- dbGetQuery(conn = db, 'SELECT savings FROM db')
        savings <- paste0("Average savings: $", mean(qs$savings))
        print(savings)
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        df <- dbGetQuery(conn = db, 'SELECT * FROM db')
        df.melt <- melt(df, id = "month")
        p <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(month)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = value, fill = variable), position = "identity")
        plot(p)
      })
    }
  )
```

Which solution would be more elegant and less resource intensive? Also, are there things that I may have missed out when comparing the two solutions? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added sample code. Would like to rephrase my question to: Would it be better to
**1) store the database as a reactive variable once**
or
**2) extract the relevant data only when a function requires it (but many more times)**

Comment: For the case of a very large data set, bringing the entire table into R may not even be an option, due to memory limitations.  In practice, what is usually done in the app languages (e.g. Java, C#, etc.) is to perform caching on some level.  Data which is being read in frequently can be cached, with other data not being cached.  What you do depends on the exact data use of that data.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]! At the current state your question is to broad. Show what you have tried and where is you programming problem. Please edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52159768/edit